# How to convert NVARCHAR value to dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM format in mssql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I know I am not the first to ask this ,I am trying to insert a **string** value **"18-05-2018 11:09:31 AM"** to the column which has the **DATETIME** as datatype in mssql.

Which returns the error as

```
The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.
```

I have tried some solutions for converting string to datetime but I could not get the expected format of output .

I want to insert the same format of the String value Which I have mentioned above to the column has DATETIME format.

Can anyone help me to solve this .

Comment: I don't see any insert statement.  Just insert an ANSI complaint timestamp, e.g. `2018-05-18 11:09:31` and it should work without needing to use conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate nvarchar(100)
SET @StartDate='18-05-2018 11:09:31 PM'
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @StartDate, 105)
```

You will have this result:

[image]

Comment: I want the data as in this format 18-05-2018 11:09:31 AM

Comment: Try this one: select convert(varchar(50),@StartDate,105) as Datetime